# How to do a 301 Redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am on a windows webhosting site ([Winhost](https://www.winhost.com/)).

Question 1: Is this an apache server where I can use .htaccess?

[Question 2: If it is how do I do a 301 redirect? What do I write in my .htaccess so index.aspx in my root dirertory goes to index.html in my root directory?]

**Edit:** the answer to Q2 is no, it does not support .htaccess files.

Question 3: If winhost is not an apache server, what do I do then? What do I put in my index.aspx file to make it go to index.html in a safe way?

Comment: Why don't you ask your hosting service company or read the documentation?

Comment: No, it does not appear to support .htaccess files.

Comment: Most likely, given the name "winhost", that is a hosting platform based on MS-Windows systems. Very exotic, but ok... Most likely that would mean that a MS-IIS is used instead of the standard apache http server.

Comment: Oh, right: MS-IIS servers use "web.conf" files instead of `.htaccess` style dynamic configuration files. Maybe that is a good point to start reading for you: https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig